# How to test for methane gas purity?

Tags: thermodynamics, home-experiment, gas-phase-chemistry

I use methane gas for cooking and there are times in which, despite burners being clean,
the flame doesn't burn that well and/or is quite red.
I suspect that said gas actually has some air added in, either intentionally as a fraud or not,
and would like to test for its purity.
Are there any ways I'd check this?

Thank you

Comment: Difficult at home, without a GC MS. And the responsible people at your gas supplier would be criminally liable if they mixed in anything. Unlikely, I´d say.

Comment: Pipe line gas , delivered to a home ? Depends where and when to speculate on other stuff may be present. Ethane is probably not unusual . It would increase the heating value so air may be added to keep a constant BTU/ Volume ( usually the basis for billing) , depending where you are /what the rules are.  I think you need to know what may be in it to analyse for it.

Comment: And it likely contains a ppm +/- of mercaptan for smell depending where you are.

Comment: Btw. gas *does* contain quite an amount of nitrogen, carbon dioxide, etc., around ten percent. Varied with ethane content, to keep the energy content per volume constant afaik.

Comment: During my time of doing Work-Study Chemistry, We have used a bubbler through which a vacuum pump pulled the gas through a solvent, the impurities would then be examined throughout the solvent. Similar in nature to an acetone wash, however, it is done with a molecule in gas format.